# Product of Indicator function

Tags: functions, random-variables, products

I was solving a question and in an intermediate step, I need to solve the following product:

$$\prod_{k=1}^N\mathbb{1}_{\{y_k\geq1\}}$$

Is there a way to simplify it or write it in a closed-form expression?

I could only think of the following expression:

$\mathbb{1}_A.\mathbb{1}_B = \mathbb{1}_{A\cap B}$, so the expression would look like $\mathbb{1}_{{\{y_1\geq1},{y_2\geq1},{y_3\geq1}\dots{y_N\geq1\}}}$

Comment: What is $1_{\{y_k\geqslant1\}}$?

Comment: $y_k$ are some iid distributed random variables, and the indicator function takes value 1 whenever $y_k \geq 1$.

Comment: your expression is right: you can see it better if you use the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)

Comment: A different way to write this is
$$
\prod_{k=1}^N\mathbb{I}_{\{y_k\geq1\}}
 = \mathbb{I}_{\bigcap_{k=1}^N \{y_k \ge 1\}}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question often arises in statistics for the likelihood with an uniform density.

Pending you know the value of each $y_i$, we can talk about [order statistics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) : $y_{(1)}=\min_i y_i, \dots, y_{(N)}=\max_i y_i$.

Looking at your product, it is equal to 0 as soon as one $y_i$ is smaller than 1. Thus, you want the smallest $y_i$ to be bigger than 1. We have $$\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^N \mathbb{1}_{\{y_k\ge1\}} = \mathbb{1}_{\{y_{(1)}\ge1\}}.$$

It is easier to maximize/minimize the likelihood now.